# NodeJS no Azure

Tags: node.js, microsoft-azure

Fiz um projeto público simples em NodeJS de API.
https://github.com/andreraica/NodeAPI

Porem ao publicar e acessar a API no AZURE não respondeu: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Rodando local funciona perfeitamente.
[image: Localhost]

Fiz todos os procedimentos possiveis de publicação e o Build do GIT apresenta tudo ok pelo portal da Azure.

Alguem tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: De uma olhada em como ficou a estrutura de diretorios no WebApp. Vc se certificou que o WebApp está aguardando uma aplicação NodeJS? Qual versao do WebApp está usando? WebApp ou WebApp on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

consegui resolver.
Precisa usar a varíavel de ambiente de portas (`process.env.PORT`), conforme abaixo.

---

Código errado:

```
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Servidor rodando na porta. server<<' + process.env.PORT + '>> ou local<<3000>>');
});
```

Código corrigido:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log('Servidor rodando na porta. server<<' + process.env.PORT + '>> ou local<<3000>>');
});
```

Valeu pela força